# Solidity OpenZeppelin get balanceOf() erc1155 token from given address

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin

I was looking for simple implementation of checking balanceOf ERC1155 with given _tokenId using openzeppelin library but I haven't found any. Please Help me how can I use this method in smartcontract by showing any smple function with correct constructor settings

```
function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns (uint256);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `balanceOf` function defined in EIP-1155. This is also available on the OpenZepplin implementation: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol#L70

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I made function:

```
function getTokenBalance(address _contractAddr, uint256 _tokenId) view public returns (uint256) {
    ERC1155 token = ERC1155(_contractAddr);
    return token.balanceOf(msg.sender, _tokenId);
}
```

Comment: I will move it to mapping addr -> balances if it ill be necessery.